# Query DB2 Timestamp column by date only

Tags: db2

Apologies if that question has an answer elsewhere, but I couldn't find anything matching exactly my problem.
I have a timestamp column. Now I want to query that column for all rows matching a given date (day) only. I tried

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE created = '2024-02-12'
```

but that gives just a blank result. So, is there a way to search a timestamp column just by date (or time, respectively) portions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your column from Timestamp to Date :

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE DATE(created) = '2024-02-12'
```

Comment: Though correct is much more efficient to change the predicate to `created >= '2024-02-12 00:00:00' and created < '2024-02-13 00:00:00'.

Answer (score 0):

Cast your timestamp column to date and test :

```
select *
from MyTable                           
where cast(created as date)='2024-02-12'
```